# A Theory of Moderation page not found in Stack Apps tour page

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, 404-not-found, stackapps

In the [Stack Apps tour page](https://stackapps.com/tour),
the `A Theory of Moderation` [link](https://stackapps.com/Current.Settings.Translations.TheoryOfModerationUrl) leads to a 404 error:

***Red marked line in picture:***

[image: problematic link in tour page]

Reason is that the URL is not rendered, and is showing the raw `https://stackapps.com/Current.Settings.Translations.TheoryOfModerationUrl`.

Comment: Huh, that's an odd bug.